# What is the reason to use parenthesis-less subroutine calls in Perl?

Tags: perl, coding-style, call, subroutine, parentheses

As per [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> The & is optional in modern Perl, as are parentheses if the subroutine has been predeclared.

I notice that a lot of times, people use the fact that you can omit parenthesis when calling Perl subroutines (e.g., randomly quoting from a recent SO answer):

```
open my $fin, '<', $file;
```

is as equally valid as

```
open(my $fin, '<', $file);
```

**What are the main (ideally, technical) reasons to use the second (parenthesis-less) version?**

[perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) doesn't say anything on the topic other than again mention optionality.

For me, always using the parenthesis are mostly a stylistic choice due to my origins as a C developer; but **I'd like to know if I'm missing something out on not using the optional parenthesis-less syntax** as a Perl developer.

---

P.S. I know full well the reasons to prefer the version with parenthesis - e.g. [the issues with indirect object notation](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problems-with-indirect-object-notation.html), or [requirement to declare non-builtins before they are used without parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992715/why-is-parenthesis-optional-only-after-sub-declaration), or issues with precedence visavi `or` vs `||`. I'm interested in the opposite.

---

P.P.S. I'm not greatly interested in answers merely stating "it's better style"/"more readable" without any studies backing the opinion up. I'm interested in either technical reasons to prefer parenthesis omission, or **backed up** stylistic difference preferences (Please don't confuse "backed up" with "appeal to authority" or ["argumentum ad populum"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) fallacies. A study showing improvement in speed or comprehension of code is proof. "Everyone in Perl commmunity agrees" or "Damien Conway suggests this" without explaining how Damien backs this up is not).

Comment: I don't use the parens to distinguish built-ins. That's about the only rule I follow.

Comment: @ugexe - is there a major reason to distinguish built-ins? Or just habit?

Comment: Conway's suggestion seems to provide reasons that are entirely cosmetic/stylistic.  As `CodeLayout::ProhibitParensWithBuiltins` is one of `Perl::Critic`'s built-in rules many coders probably find it easier to comply than to edit their `.perlcriticrc`.  Choose the option that suits you best....

Comment: I think this is because `perl` wants to support different coding styles. One who used to program is shell it is very common to use the form `printf "%d\n" $arg1;`. For a C coder it is more preferable the `printf("%d\n", arg1);` style. In `perl` both can be used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the only time that it actually matters, other than style, is for the rarely used `&subname` which according to [perldoc perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub):

```
&NAME;     # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

Of course, using parens might make for easier disambiguation in some cases (both for the parser and the future reader), or else not using them might remove noise in others; the degree to which either of those is necessary is probably the primary reason I would ever choose one or the other.

Answer (score 10):

From [Perl::Critic::Policy::CodeLayout::ProhibitParensWithBuiltins](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic::Policy::CodeLayout::ProhibitParensWithBuiltins):

> Conway suggests that all built-in functions be called without
>   parentheses around the argument list. This reduces visual clutter and
>   disambiguates built-in functions from user functions.

Conway is the author of the *Perl Best Practices* book.

Comment: Note that it only disambiguates if you never call a user function without parens.

Comment: This doesn't explain (1) Why it's beneficial to distinguish between built-ins and user functions; and (2) seems to suggest that there's NO  side benefit aside from such disambiguation...

Comment: There is no side benefit unless you use the & with the subroutine name as Joel Berger explained. I personally prefer using parentheses because it helps me visually distinguish the parameters from anything else on the line e.g. `open(my $FILE, "<", $filename) or die("Can not open $filename: $!");`

Comment: @imran Do you also write `print("Hi!\n");`?

Comment: @darch I guess print is an exception. I wouldn't use parentheses for short strings, and not if I am specifying a file handle. I might if it has multiple arguments or something like a join in it.

Answer (score 7):

There are no technical reasons to omit parentheses.  It's purely a matter of preferred coding style.

Answer (score 3):

This is purely a style question.  To a Perl programmer, `print "Hi!\n";` is more readable than `print("Hi!\n");`.  It is good style to make code as readable as possible, and -- all else being equal -- additional symbols make reading harder.  Since built-ins don't need the parens, it makes sense to ask whether the disambiguation they provide justifies the additional cognitive load.  And Perl programmers as a class have come down on the side of "no", aided in part by Damien Conway's formalization of the rule.

Conway also suggests that keeping built-ins paren-free helps distinguish them from user-defined functions, but I consider that argument less persuasive.  It is more correct to say that many built-ins are designed to read naturally without parens, and so should be used that way.  Seeing `defined($x)` or `len($y)` makes Perl programmers twitch, but no more than seeing `croak($z)`.

Note that writing Perl as though it were C is emphatically *bad* style.  Write Perl as though it were Perl.

Comment: I know that "bad style" is a fashionable opinion, but why?

Comment: @dvk What does that question mean?  'Why is "bad style" considered a problem?'?  'Why is writing Perl as though it were C bad style?'?  'Why is writing readable code good style?'?  In other words, does your question have a connection to the answer above -- and if so what is it -- or is it mere trolling?

Comment: #2. 'Why is writing Perl as though it were C bad style?'. Other than "because everyone who writes Perl likes it subjectively", is there something that makes parenthecised calling of subs "bad"?

Comment: And "it's more readable" is not a proven assertion without actual usability tests, e.g. having double blind test where people try to read both styles of code.

Comment: @DVK Oh, dear, the insistence of provable assertions is a significant sign that your question was posed in bad faith.  With that in mind, I am done with this.  I have given you a true answer to your question; if you don't wish to know it, I cannot further help you.

Comment: your answer consisted of (1) Info that was already on other answers (Conway), and subjective assertion about style preference that you keep insisting I have no right to be skeptical about - despite the fact that the question stressed the interest in **technical** differences. Rejecting subjective non-backed-up opinions isn't bad faith.