# Perl subroutines - do they need to be called with parentheses?

Tags: perl, subroutine

I built a simple subroutine, and I have a question about whether calling it requires parentheses.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub echo {
    print "@_ \n" ;
}
echo(@ARGV);
```

When I use

```
echo @ARGV
```

or

```
echo (@ARGV)
```

or (without a space)

```
echo(@ARGV)
```

they all work. Which one is correct?

Comment: [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)?

Comment: `perldoc perlstyle` recommends `No space between function name and its opening parenthesis.`  Using parentheses makes it clear that it is a user-defined function, as opposed to a built-in.

Comment: @xxfelixxx: Good info re space, but just to be clear: I assume you're recommending adopting the _convention_ of calling all user-defined functions _with_ parentheses, and built-ins _without_ (technically, however, built-ins _can_ be called _with_ parentheses, and user-defined functions _can_ be called _without_ parentheses, if predeclared).

Comment: The linked question that some consider this question to be a duplicate of has a different focus: The linked question knows under what circumstances parentheses are needed, and asks _why_ that is so.
By contrast, _this_ question asks about _whether_ parentheses are needed, whether a space in front of the opening parentheses matters, and when to choose which invocation style.

Comment: @mklement0 Agreed, voted to reopen. I'm really surprised there isn't a suitable duplicate for this.

Answer (score 5):

`echo @ARGV`, `echo (@ARGV)`, and `echo(@ARGV)` are technically *all* correct in your case, but using **parentheses** is ***sometimes* necessary**; beyond that, it's a **matter of choice**, and some people employ **conventions** around when to use what style.

- **Enclosing the entire argument list in parentheses ALWAYS works** - whether spaces precede the opening parenthesis or not - `echo (@ARGV)` or `echo(@ARGV)` - and whether you're calling a built-in or user-defined function (subroutine):

  - As @xxfelixxx notes in a comment on the question, `perldoc perlstyle` recommends *no* spaces between the function name and `(` - `echo(@ARGV)`.
  - Enclosing the entire argument list in parentheses **can be used to *disambiguate***:

    - `print (1 + 2) + 4` prints only `3`, because `(1 + 2)` is interpreted as the *entire* argument list (with `+ 4` added to the the expression value of the `print` call, the result of which is not output).
    - `print((1 + 2) + 4)` resolves the ambiguity and prints `7`.
    - Alternatively, prefix the parenthesized first argument with `+` to achieve the same effect: `print +(1 + 2) + 4` also prints `7`.
- ***Not* using parentheses** - `echo @ARGV` - works:

  - with ***built-in* functions: *always***
  - with ***user-defined* functions: ONLY if they are *predeclared***, which can be ensured in one of the following ways:

    - The function is *defined* in the same script *before* its invocation.
    - The function is *forward-declared* with `sub <name>;` *before* its invocation.
    - The function is *imported* from a module with `use` *before* its invocation (`require` is not enough).
  - This predeclaration requirement is is an unfortunate side effect of backward compatibility with the earliest Perl versions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5992858/45375).
  - In the **absence of a predeclaration, the safest approach is to use parentheses** (while `&echo @ARGV` works in principle, it bypasses any prototypes (a form of parameter typing) that the function may declare).

As for **conventions**:

- Since using parentheses *always works* (even when not strictly needed) with *user-defined* functions, whereas they are never *needed* for *built-in* functions, some people recommend *always* using parentheses with *user-defined* functions, and *never* with *built-in* functions.
  In source code that adheres to this convention, looking at any function call then tells you whether a built-on or user-defined function is being invoked.

Answer (score 2):

The parens are optional. You need them in some situations to explicitly show which values are the arguments to the function, for example, when passing the result of a function call to another function:

```
myfunc(1, 2, otherfunc(3), "z");
```

Without parens around the 3, `otherfunc` will receive both 3 and "z" as arguments.

As xxfelixxx mentioned, it's best to use them all the time.